# Exracting data/value of given xpath in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, xpath, web-scraping, extract, screen-scraping

I am able to extract the xpath of any element present in document but not able to **extract its contents/value/data**. for example :

```
<div class="container" title="DivA">
DivA
<div id="container" title="#DivB">
    #DivB
    <div title="DivC (div)">
        DivC (div)
    </div>
    <span title="SpanD (span)">
        SpanD (span)
        <ul>
            <li title="Bullet 1">Bullet 1</li>
            <li id="bullet2" title="Bullet 2">Bullet 2 (#bullet2)</li>
            <li title="Bullet 3">Bullet 3</li>
        </ul>
    </span>
          <img src="favicon.ico">
         <a href="http://google.com/">Dummy Href</a>
</div>
```

> i need the content which is in between tags
>   for example:
>   var path = //*[@id='container']/span[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jiPMm.png)/ul[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jiPMm.png)/li[3]; //path for Bullet 3
>   var data = path.value         // or any thing which can help to extract data.
>    var data  will be Bullet 3

xpath extraction screenshot:
[image: Xpath for image without @src]

Comment: Try `//*[@id='container']/span[1]/ul[1]/li[3]/text()` to select text node instead of element

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `document.evaluate` to accomplish this..

Like this:

```js
var li = document.evaluate( "//*[@id='container']/span[1]/ul[1]/li[1]", document, null, XPathResult.STRING_TYPE, null);
var a = document.evaluate("//*[@id='container']/span[1]/a/@href",document, null, XPathResult.STRING_TYPE, null);
console.log(li.stringValue);
console.log(a.stringValue);
```

```html
<div class="container" title="DivA">
DivA
<div id="container" title="#DivB">
    #DivB
    <div title="DivC (div)">
        DivC (div)
    </div>
    <span title="SpanD (span)">
        SpanD (span)
        <a href="https://google.com">Google</a>
        <ul>
            <li title="Bullet 1">Bullet 1</li>
            <li id="bullet2" title="Bullet 2">Bullet 2 (#bullet2)</li>
            <li title="Bullet 3">Bullet 3</li>
        </ul>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: what if i want to extract src from an image xpath and href xpath
var path = //*[@id='container']/img[1]; 
var data = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/cb/Foo_was_here.jpg"                                           //image source(src)

Comment: see my updated answer.. I added example of `href ` extraction with xpath

Comment: This time i need href **link** and  **src** as output from both href and image element.

Comment: Well my example shows how to extract href from a.. The same goes for extracting src from img.. In both cases you are trying to extract an attribute (href or src). The xpath you want in src case is this: `//*[@id='container']/img[1]/@src`

Comment: I am trying to automate the process and i am not getting /@src and /@href at the end of xpath ??

Comment: What do you mean "not getting"? How are you generating the xpath?

Comment: i have update my question with screenshot please refer

Comment: I am finding difficult to take a screenshot of selected area in the browser. it will be very thankful to u if u might help.